# Prove: $|x-y|\leq |x|+|y|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Can you help me to prove that
$$|x-y|\leq |x|+|y|$$
I get a proff of this equality, but it's very short and I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: It follows from the triangle inequality, letting $y = -z$ you get that 

$$|x + y| = |x - z| \leq |x| + |-z| = |x| + |z|$$

Comment: can you tell us what you've tried? Why do you think your proof is not correct?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307348/proof-of-triangle-inequality) with $-y$ instead of $y$, because $\lvert -y\rvert=\lvert y\rvert$.

Comment: Or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188114/a-b%e2%89%a4ab-is-always-true).

Comment: You don't bother to search for the question. And you are asking similar questions without showing any work or sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the square root of this:
$$
(x-y)^2=x^2+y^2-2xy\leq x^2+y^2+2|x||y|=(|x|+|y|)^2
$$
and get
$$
|x-y|\leq |x|+|y|
$$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $|x| = \max\{x,-x\}$

Thus  $\pm x ≤ |x|$.

Then you can observe that :

\begin{align*}
x + y &≤ |x| + y ≤ |x| + |y|,\quad\text{and}\\
-x - y &≤ |x| -y ≤ |x| + |y|.
\end{align*}

So we have that $|x+y| \leq |x|+|y|$

Now put $x=X$ and $y=-Y$ ,

Thus $$|X-Y| \leq |X|+|-Y|$$

Since $|-Y|=|Y|$ ,
$$|X-Y| \leq |X|+|Y|$$

Answer (score -1):

$$\sqrt{(x-y)^2}\leqslant \sqrt{x^2}+\sqrt{y^2}$$
$$\sqrt{x^2-2xy+y^2}\leqslant \sqrt{x^2}+\sqrt{y^2}$$
$$x^2-2xy+y^2\leqslant x^2+y^2+2\sqrt{y^2x^2}$$

Comment: It appears to me that the OP is asking for a proof of the triangle inequality, not an "assertion" that it holds.  Also, your statements are false (when $x=y=0$ for example).